# (admin.E108) The value of 'list_display[1]' refers to 'label', which is not a callable, an attribute of '?', or an attribute or method on 'org.Org'

Tags: django, django-models

I get the error : (admin.E108) The value of 'list_display[1]' refers to 'label', which is not a callable, an attribute of 'OrgAdmin', or an attribute or method on 'org.Org'. when I try to remove the field label, I don't understand why. (sqlite3)

It feels like django has referenced that field somewhere (I was using it in the **str** function before refactoring and I don't know how to sync it up or something.

```
from django.db import models


class Org(models.Model):
  class Meta:
    # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/options/#django.db.models.Options.db_table
    db_table = "tfp_backoffice_org"
    verbose_name = 'Organization'

    # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/options/#indexes
    indexes = [
      models.Index(fields=['name', 'name']),
    ]

  name = models.CharField(
    help_text="Optional (autogenerated).<br />"
              "Must be url-compliant (slug, using '-' dash separator, no space, special char, etc.)",
    max_length=100,
  )
  label = models.CharField(
    help_text="Label displayed in French language",
    max_length=100,
  )
  label_fr = models.CharField(
    help_text="Label displayed in French language",
    max_length=100,
    blank=True,
    default="",
  )
  label_en = models.CharField(
    help_text="Label displayed in English language",
    max_length=100,
    blank=True,
    default="",
  )

  def __str__(self):
    return self.label_fr
```

Comment: Post your Admin class

Comment: Yes, indeed, the problem was with the Admin class but I didn't see it despite the error message

Comment: Also, why did someone asked to close this for being "off-topic" with programming? That's totally related to programming.

Comment: Because some people... You know. If you solved it, add your own answer. Maybe it will help someone in the future

Comment: Yeah... Thank you anyway. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error wasn't in the model (as stated in the error message) but in the `admin.py` file.

```
from django.contrib import admin

from org.models import Org


class OrgAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
  list_display = ('name', 'label')  # The error was there


admin.site.register(Org, OrgAdmin)
```

The problem was pretty obvious, I kept looking into the model.py instead of the admin.py. I guess I missed the obvious. Hope this helps someone in the future!

Comment: It was 2am ^_^', that's my official excuse ahah

Comment: Happens to all of us

Comment: I have exatly same error. But what wrong with your 'list_display'???

Comment: @swasher The `label` column was wrong, either it was named differently, or didn't exist. I don't remember, but removing "label" from the list fixed the issue

Answer (score -1):

I had this error but with a different cause.  I had a field defined in the models.py file:

`transaction_date = models.DateField(name="Date")`

The name="Date" was to change the field label.
The admin.py had to use the "Date"  and not "transaction_date":

```
class AllTransactionsAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ("Date", etc)
```